# How to get DataGridTemplateColumn Header Binding working?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

A `Window` contains some elements plus a `DataGrid`. The `DataContext` of the `Window` is set to a `ViewModel`, and the `DataGrid` is bound to a `Property` of the `ViewModel`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredMessages}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

Now I'd like to bind the `Header`s of the `Column`s to properties of the `ViewModel`, like e.g.:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding TimeColumnHeaderText}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding (logging:LogMessage.Time), StringFormat=\{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff\}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

While the contents of the grid is shown correctly, the Header fails to bind.

I've found a description of a BindingProxy at http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ but failed to get it working. That solution requires a Resource in the DataGrid

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <wpfUtilities:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

and a reference to that proxy in the `Binding` clause:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding TimeColumnHeaderText, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
```

I replaced `{Binding}` in the resources section with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}` but the property is not found on the proxy:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'TimeColumnHeaderText' property not found on 'object' ''BindingProxy'
```

Also tried to move the proxy to the resources section of the window, didn't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, you bound `{Binding}` to the proxy's `Data` property:

```
<wpfUtilities:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

That line was correct the way you originally had it. It's the binding that's wrong. The proxy isn't itself a reference to the viewmodel. Its `Data` property is the reference to the viewmodel. You just neglected one tiny detail in the example: You need to include the source's `Data` property in the path to your viewmodel property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="{Binding Data.TimeColumnHeaderText, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" 
    Width="Auto" 
    IsReadOnly="True"
    >
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But it's sad that ReSharper now complains with a `Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved` warning.

Comment: The ReSharper warning could be resolved with a generic BindingProxy<T> and a local derived class LoggingBindingProxy : BindingProxy<LogViewModel> in place of the original proxy in XAML.

Comment: ReSharper warnings are best resolved by uninstalling ReSharper and signing up everybody at JetBrains to a Nigerian spam list.